# iPhone : Unable to find "Two-device specific application" option in Xcode4

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4

[image]

Where do i find this option in Xcode4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the target. Then Xcode4 asks you if you want to make a iPad version of that target.

Comment: Does it make different xib for iPad and iPhone ?

Comment: Don't know. Haven't tested it. You could test it on a dummy project.