# Two device-specific applications xcode 7

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad app and want to port it also to iPhone, but on the iPhone it should have different look. The app is built with xib files.

I have been looking for [iPhone : Unable to find "Two-device specific application" option in Xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882183/iphone-unable-to-find-two-device-specific-application-option-in-xcode4) or something similar, but just can't find it.

Can someone help me how to do this in xcode7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Devices option in Project -> target -> general to Universal.
So you can run iPad app in iPhone.

Comment: I've been looking into this, but do I understand it right and have to first rename all of my current files into file_iPad and then add additional files for iphone?

Comment: You don't need to rename, Instead if you want to keep separate UI for iPad and iPhone, you may need to create new nib files for iPhone and integrate it to the project and load nib files according to device.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Universal Application, use Autolayout and Adaptive layout for all UIDesign , then we can run the app on any device without any Design conflict

Comment: I know that I can create an universal app from start, but I already have an app about year old and don't want to build it from start.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this will be to create a universal app. And use autolayout size classes to handle the different size classes and looks.